# Ubuntu 14.04 and Samsung NP910S5J

Tags: 14.04, samsung

I would like to buy the Samsung NP910S5J notebook.
I would like to know if installing ubuntu 14.04 there can be problems.
Has someone already done it?
Thank you

Comment: Are you buying it specifically for Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the preinstalled windows

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung NP910S5J notebook is a one of the laptops in the Samsung Series 9. According to the official Ubuntu [Samsung Series 9](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SamsungSeries9) documentation:

> All essential features of Samsung Series 9 laptops work out of the box on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every computer that isn't ARM and was manufactured after the year 2000 should work with Ubuntu. Newer computers (2015) may need 15.10, as the newest Intel processors are too new to work on the kernels that come with Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04. Since that computer looks like it has an i5, and not one of the newer ones, Ubuntu should not be a problem.